# Google Analytics Ecommerce Tracking minimum price?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

is there minimum value for price?
can I send items with price of 0.00085 for example?

```
   ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
      'id': '53d8c003cf07a6.46359058',  // Transaction ID. Required.
      'name': '6',    // Product name. Required.
      'price': '0.00182',                 // Unit price.
      'quantity': '1'                   // Quantity.
    });
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sent whatever you want, but only two decimal places are displayed in the interface so your "micropayments" will show up with a zero revenue (I tested this with enhanced ecommerce but I don't think the interface will behave differently with standard ecommerce).

**Update**: I repeated my test to get an answer for the comment below. I found that a) yes, product revenue is summed up in the product performance reports, b) it seems that the way this is displayed has changed a bit since I last tested this -  there is now a "less than" sign to indicate that product revenue is less than 0.01 (see screenshot).

[image]

Comment: tnx so if i understand you right if i send 0.001X100 times i will see in my revenu 0.01? or it will not sum up?